# Standard ML error:operator and operand don't agree

Tags: sml

I want to write a function `number_before_reaching_sum` that takes an int called sum, and return an int n such that the first n elements of the list add to less than sum, but the first n + 1 elements of the list add to sum or more.
Here's my code

```
 fun number_before_reaching_sum(sum:int,lists:int list)=
 let
 val sum_list=0
 val n=0
 in
     let fun list_compute(sum_list:int,lists2:int list,n:int)=
           let val sum_list2=sum_list+(hd lists2)
           in if sum_list2>=sum
                  then (sum_list2,n+1)
              else (#1 list_compute(sum_list2,tl lists2,n+1),#2 list_compute(sum_list2,tl lists2,n+1))
               end
     in   #2 list_compute(sum_list,lists,n)
     end
 end
```

The error message prints out:

```
    hw1_1.sml:67.14-67.97 Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
  operator domain: {1:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         int * int list * int -> 'X
  in expression:
    (fn {1=1,...} => 1) list_compute
hw1_1.sml:67.14-67.97 Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
  operator domain: {2:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         int * int list * int -> 'X
  in expression:
    (fn {2=2,...} => 2) list_compute
hw1_1.sml:69.11-69.44 Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
  operator domain: {2:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         int * int list * int -> int * int
  in expression:
    (fn {2=2,...} => 2) list_compute
```

I cannot figure out why `(#1 list_compute(sum_list2,tl lists2,n+1),#2 list_compute(sum_list2,tl lists2,n+1))`and `#2 list_compute(sum_list,lists,n)`
this 2 lines are wrong.

Comment: In general, if you get errors like this in Standard ML it's because you forgot to wrap some expression in parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f g(x,y)` gets parsed as `(f g) (x,y)`, not `f (g (x,y))`. So you want to add parentheses like this:

```
#1 (list_compute (sum_list2,tl lists2,n+1))
```

Otherwise it tries to apply `#1` to the function `list_compute`. The error message is the compiler telling you "`#1` wants a tuple, but you gave it a function instead".